# Grounds for permanent deletions

Tags: support, deleted-posts, redacting-edits

What are the grounds for permanent deletion of a question on this group? That is: total deletion with no-one able to see or undelete the question.

Comment: I'm talking about a question which doesn't show up at all, even in the 'recently deleted questions' tab. I assume it's been deleted in such a way that no-one can see it. Other, older questions still show up there.

Comment: I have heard stories about questions that were so disruptive that the people in charge had no other choice than to delete them from the database manually. This never happens with questions that are simply off topic or low quality though.

Comment: Wait, what "deleted questions" tab? Where?

Comment: I just asked a question about the Jabberwocky which invoked Postmodernism in a way that questioned the thing-frames upon which we base our language itself. I hardly see how that would have been disruptive to an English based group...

Comment: We're all down with the free play of signs and signifiers here, right? Right?

Comment: @MrLister http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/how-do-i-find-a-question-which-was-deleted

Comment: I'm not familiar with these kinds of "super deletions". All deleted questions I'm aware of could be undeleted by community consensus or at least a diamond mod. I'm sure diamond mods, or if not them, then community managers, can completely obliterate certain kinds of content (I know they can redact the edit history of a post, for example), but the only time I've sent this employed is when it puts a person at actual risk (eg doxing someone, threatening someone, etc) or illegal content (for some definition of illegal, e.g. certain types of pornography).

Comment: For normal "bad content", such as low-quality posts, or even further down the food chain, vandalism, spam, or offensive content, normal deletion is usually sufficient and employed (because no one is going to undelete bad content).

Comment: It's back now. Weird.

Comment: Oh, your Jabberwocky question? If you have a link to where it used to be, I can tell you if 10K+ users can still see it (I imagine we can). It probably fell off your "recently deleted" tab because it wasn't deleted all that recently any more....

Comment: See above. It's just reappeared. Temporary glitch or something... obvs.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Well bear in mind one day it will stop appearing in your "recently deleted" tab, so save the URL now if you want to be able to refer to it later. Though once that happens you'll need 10K+ rep to see it. Might as well copy/paste the Markdown, download the page entirely, or simply screenshot the entire page, save it somewhere convenient for yourself, and forget it ever appeared on SE in the first place.

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get 10K+ rep on here while still alive *sighs forlorn sighs and thinks about finishing the end of my novel*

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter downvotes on meta are different from those on main. Here they just mean 'I disagree'. BTW, there are no explicit grounds for deleting, it's all just votes that people choose to make.Also, no permanent deletion. If you have a link you can visit it.

Comment: @Mitch Are there specific grounds for voting up or down on the main EL&U site? It would be useful if there were. All I can see is the usual SE grounds including *research effort*. Are those still applicable. If so, how does one show research effort on EL&U?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter grounds? sure, too long to list. spend some time here reading to see what the patterns are. one example, for a single word request, at least look at a thesaurus first, also explain in detail what the words properties should be. for grammar, at least do a google search for the phrases you're comparing. Do the pretty obvious stuff. Don't make other people do what you can already do yourself. Help them help you.

Comment: You don't need 10K+ rep to see your own deleted questions, from what I remember.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleted answers vs deleted questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/deleted-answers-vs-deleted-questions)

Comment: @Mari-LouA That meta question is about the technological difference between deleted questions and deleted answers. This is about what the justifiable reasons there are for absolute permanent deletion.

Comment: @Mitch my answer on the link explains how and when a question is permanently deleted. The OP asks what "grounds" (factors)  are there for *permanent* deletions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh. I suspected that the OPs question here is answered elsewhere but would not have expected there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators redact content that contains contact information (like email address or phone number), personally identifying details, passwords, or connection strings. We will often honor a request to redact content that may have potentially harmful impact to a poster as well -- this doesn't usually happen on EL&U, but occasionally happens on SO or Workplace, for instance when someone has inadvertently posted proprietary code or revealed trade secrets.

We can redact both posts and chat messages. Redactions of posts have to be approved by a second. Any time we redact an edit or purge a chat message, that action is logged and the community moderation team is made aware of it.

Otherwise, editing or deletion is sufficient.

Comment: In addition to PII, I imagine mods are chartered to redact anything which puts SE, Inc. at legal risk? Like libel against a living person, or inappropriate pictures, that kind of thing? Basically in addition to anything that creates a risk for a person, anything hat could get SE, Inc. brought to court?

Comment: @Dan I can't say that I've ever heard tell of any incidents like that. We would remove prurient images.